# Firestore addDoc not storing whole object

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Hi I'm having an issue with firebase when I call an addDoc passing object (useState Hook).

The thing is that sometimes the object is stored with all the fields, and sometimes not (with the same data passed)

Let me put you in context. Here is how I declare the object initialy:

```
const [trade, setTrade] = useState({
  ticker: "",
  units: "",
  price: "",
  result_balance: "",
  createdAt: todaysDate,
  direction: "",
  status: true,
  cprice: "",
  closedAt:"",
});
```

This is the function where i call addDoc in order to save the data the data into firestore:

```
const saveTrade = async (e) => {

  trade.createdAt = todaysDate;
  trade.ticker = trade.ticker.toUpperCase()

  if(trade.cprice){
    trade.closedAt =todaysDate;
  }
  try {
    await addDoc(
      collection(
        db,
        "journals",
        window.location.pathname.replace("/journal", ""),
        "entries"
      ),
      trade. //Passing the object here
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  
  setTrade({});
  closeHandler();
};
```

As I said sometimes it stores the object correctly: [Good scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV78I.png)

But sometimes not [Bad scenario (not all the fields created in firestore)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeEru.png)

Hope someone can give me advice or tips about how to approach this problem.

Comment: Maybe it's set to ignore undefined values? In that case it doesn't write.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing other peoples code I realised I was calling `setTrade({})` incorrectly in order to clear the fields. Now I call it like this:

```
 const saveTrade = async (e) => {

  trade.createdAt = todaysDate;
  trade.ticker = trade.ticker.toUpperCase()

  if(trade.cprice){
    trade.closedAt =todaysDate;
  }
  try {
    await addDoc(
      collection(
        db,
        "journals",
        window.location.pathname.replace("/journal", ""),
        "entries"
      ),
      trade. //Passing the object here
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  
  setTrade({
   ticker: "",
   units: "",
   price: "",
   result_balance: "",
   createdAt: todaysDate,
   direction: "",
   status: true,
   cprice: "",
   closedAt:"",
   });
  closeHandler();
};
```

Now it works perfectly.